# I can't get a stored value from my db in PHP (the stored value is a filename without extention)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a filename from a database `$oldfile` and replace it with a new one `$newfile` The problem is `$oldfile` is returning an empty value, but in the database it has a value.

```
$oldfile = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $styles=$_POST['styles'];
    $id=intval($_GET['id']);
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,"update styles set stylename='$styles' where id='$id'");

    $file = $oldfile.'.php';

    $tempfile = strtolower($styles);
    $newfile = $tempfile.'.php';

    if(!rename($file, $newfile)){
        $_SESSION['delmsg']="File Not Replaced!";
    }

    $_SESSION['msg']="Styles Updated!".$file;

}

$id=intval($_GET['id']);
$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from styles where id='$id'");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $disp = $row['stylename'];
    $oldfile = strtolower($row['stylename']);
}
```

Comment: In `$file = $oldfile.'.php';` `$oldfile` is empty.

Comment: You set it to nothing at the top `$oldfile = '';` how could it be anything other than that? I also don't see what this has to do with `mysql` as none of the code dealing with files has anything to do with your SQL. Speaking of your mysql... you are wide open for a sql injection attack here. Switch over to [mysqli's bindparam](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to save some heartache later on.

Comment: Please refer to how to create an [mcve]

Comment: Perhaps... put that last bit of code FIRST so you have `$oldFile` populated BEFORE you `UPDATE` the database and rename the files. It doesn't make any sense to do that after.

Comment: @JNevill I am not using OOP so how can I use mysqli bindparam? And how can I avoid sql injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be returning an empty variable with the very first line. What is the output if you comment out that line:

```
//$oldfile = ' ';
```

Also,FYI..., you are setting the $sql variable, but it is not being used anywhere else:

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"update styles set stylename='$styles' where id='$id'");
```

Comment: the $sql is the execution of the update query... useless but not an issue

Answer (score 0):

you must fill $oldfile variable first. Try below :

```
$oldfile = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $styles=$_POST['styles'];
    $id=intval($_GET['id']);

    $sql=mysqli_query($con,"update styles set stylename='$styles' where id='$id'");

    $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from styles where id='$id'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $disp = $row['stylename'];
        $oldfile = strtolower($row['stylename']);

        $file = $oldfile.'.php';

        $tempfile = strtolower($styles);
        $newfile = $tempfile.'.php';

        if(!rename($file, $newfile)){
            $_SESSION['delmsg']="File Not Replaced!";
        }

        $_SESSION['msg']="Styles Updated!".$file;
    }
}
```